# Como subir un archivo a ftp con php

Tags: php, html

Este es mi codigo de php

```
<?php
$ftp_server="192.168.1.131";
$ftp_usuario="servidor";
$ftp_pass="servidor";
$con_id=ftp_connect($ftp_server);
$lr=ftp_login($con_id, $ftp_usuario, $ftp_pass);
if ((!$con_id) || (!$lr) ) {
    echo 'No se pudo conectar.';
    exit;
} else {
    echo 'Conectado correctamente.';
   
 $temp=explode(".", $_FILES['archivo']['name']);
    $source_file=$_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
    $destino="archivos";
    $nombre=$_FILES["archivo"]['name'];
    //ftp_pass($con_id, true);
    $subio=ftp_put($con_id, $destino.'/'.$nombre, $source_file, FTP_BINARY);
    if ($subio) {
        echo "Se subió el archivo correctamente."
    } else {
        echo "Ocurrió un error.";
    }
 }
?>
```

y este el index

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <tittle> SUBIR ARCHIVOS</tittle>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="./subir.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
    <input type="file" name="archivo">
    <input type="submit" value="ENVIAR">
</body>
</html>
```

quiero hacer que por medio de php suba una imagen a un servidor FTP

```
$temp=explode(".", $_FILES['archivo']['name']);
    $source_file=$_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
    $destino="archivos";
    $nombre=$_FILES["archivo"]['name'];
    //ftp_pass($con_id, true);
    $subio=ftp_put($con_id, $destino.'/'.$nombre, $source_file, FTP_BINARY);
    if ($subio) {
        echo "Se subió el archivo correctamente."
    } else {
        echo "Ocurrió un error.";
    }
```

pero cuando le agrego esa parte del codigo
y pulso en el boton enviar
me tira error
cuando lo hago con esta parte nada mas
pero cuando le agrego esa parte del codigo
y pulso en el boton enviar
me tira error
cuando lo hago con esta parte nada mas

```
<?php
$ftp_server="192.168.1.131";
$ftp_usuario="servidor";
$ftp_pass="servidor";
$con_id=ftp_connect($ftp_server);
$lr=ftp_login($con_id, $ftp_usuario, $ftp_pass);
if ((!$con_id) || (!$lr) ) {
    echo 'No se pudo conectar.';
    exit;
} else {
    echo 'Conectado correctamente.';
```

la conexion funciona
por que puede ser
Cuando lo hago sin la parte que me da problemas

Foto sin el codigo que da problemas:
https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/744659733616525382/760906618547863562/unknown.png?width=845&height=475
Cuando pongo la parte del codigo que da problemas:
https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/744659733616525382/760907050556457070/unknown.png?width=845&height=475
Gracias de antemano

Comment: Existe la carpeta "archivos" en el FTP? Si solo te da error 500 agrega `ini_set("display_errors","on");` como primeria linea del script PHP y ahora te mostrara el error que esta ocurriendo

Comment: Por otro lado la conexion FTP y la transferencia son dos procesos distintos, por lo que puede funcionar el login, pero a veces no la transferencia. Puedes intentar tambien agregando `ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);` (modo pasivo) despues del `ftp_login()`